# How to JNI string type function mapping?

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have following table for method mapping:-

```
static jint sum_JNI(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jint a, jint b){
    return a + b;
}

static jint mul_JNI(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jint a, jint b){
    return a * b;
}

static jstring get_string(){
    return (jstring)"string";
}


static JNINativeMethod method_table[] = {
        {"sum_JNI", "(II)I", (void*) sum_JNI},
        {"mul_JNI", "(II)I", (void*) mul_JNI},
       // {"get_string","()C", (void*) get_string}
};
```

I don't know what is the type for jstring/string in this table. Tried above code. But it doesn't work. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `jstring` is a Java-language object.  You can't simply cast a C string literal into one with the definitions from `jni.h`.

Use the `NewStringUTF` function to create a `jstring` from a "modified" UTF-8 string literal.  The object type for method declarations is `Ljava/lang/String;` -- there is no single-character value.

See also [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) and the [interface spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).